# How To Read Input From Test Case File in C

Tags: c

Currently i am enrolled in NPTEL course. There i need to make c program as assignment.

Qusetion is in this format :-

Write a program that reads numbers which are in the range 0 to 100, till it encounters -1. Print the sum of all the integers that you have read before you encountered -1

**INPUT:
A sequence of integers separated by whitespace. There may be other integers following -1.**

How do i read input from test case file? plz help

I have used following code :-

```
while((n=scanf("%d",&n1))!=EOF)
{
printf("%d",n);
}
```

Loop is iterating properly ie if test case 1 has 5 input its running for 5 times. If test case 2 has 2 input hen iterating 2 time. But it is unable to read input . Please Help.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for scanf -- especially the part about its return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing `n` which is the number of items read. You need to print `n1`.

**EDIT:**

Your check for the `while` loop is incorrect. You need to check the value that is read i.e. `n1` but once again, you're using the value of n to check for EOF. You should be checking for -1 as well since that's what you want right?

Comment: `n` is the number of items (i.e. numbers), not characters, read.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant to write. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Not only that, but you say nothing about the bogus loop test. The OP needs to check for input error (for which scanf returns EOF), end of file (for which scanf returns 0), and for -1 in the input.